# Инициализация ссылочных полей класса с помощью геттеров

Tags: java, null

К примеру есть простой класс без конструктора

```
public class Pojo {

private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}}
```

Если вызвать getName у объекта данного класса, он возвращает null и вызов методов класса String например таких как length, isEmpty приводит к NullPointerException.
Хотелось бы узнать, если внести вот такую модификацию в getName:

```
public String getName() {
    if (name == null) {
        name = "";
    }
    return name;
}
```

Является ли такой метод хорошим тоном? Или проверку на null нужно проводить при каждом вызове getName в первом варианте?

Comment: Меня поправят надеюсь если не прав, но может задать дефолтное имя и возраст, тогда доп методом не надо писать минимум

Comment: Ваш код и есть "проверка на `null` при каждом вызове `getName`".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не очень хорошее решение: будут проблемы с тестированием и т.п. При возврате пустой строки вы не сможете проверить, реально ли в поле ничего не было записано, или же была записана пустая строка.

Логично проверять на `null` в том месте, где вызов происходит. А вообще такие объекты надо делать немутабельными.

```
public class Pojo {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Pojo (String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```